# Bug using PHP Sessions (Two Log On screens)

Tags: php, session

In the application I'm developing I'm having a bug where I direct my browser to my app's index.php, and is then properly redirected to login.php if there is no current session. My problem is that after I type in my correct details on login.php and click submit, I am linked to another login.php screen (instead of returning to index.php with an active session) and required to put in my details again. The first screen has the same CSS formatting as index.php, while the second screen doesn't.

After entering my details on the second screen and clicking login, the sessions seem to function normally. Also, many times I will be presented with one logon screen, ill login and the user's correct Home screen data will be displayed (which requires successful queries from the login data), but if I navigate away from index.php to another screen that requires an active session, it will present the unformatted login.php screen.

If I logout, navigate to a different non-restricted page, and attempt to log back in again within the same browser session, the logon functions correctly with only one screen.

Here are snippets from the relevant files:

```
    index.php
    <?php
    include_once 'db_functions.php';

    require_once 'access.php';

    if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
        if (userIsLoggedIn()) {
            header('Location: http://www.myapp.com/index.php');         //prevents users from having to confirm form resubmission if they refresh the page
        }

    }

    if (!userIsLoggedIn()) {
        include 'login.php';
        exit();
    }
```

login.php:

```
login.php
<body>
<h1>Log In</h1>

<?php
    if (isset($loginError)) {
          echo $loginError; 
    }
?>

    <form action="" method="post">
    <div>
    <label for="email">Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /> </label>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for="password">Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /></label>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login" />
    <input type="submit" value="Log in"  />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

access.php:

```
 <?php
 function userIsLoggedIn() {
    if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'login') {

        if (!isset($_POST['action']) or $_POST['email'] == '' or
        !isset($_POST['password']) or $_POST['password'] == '') {

            $GLOBALS['loginError'] = 'Please fill in both fields';
            return FALSE;
        }

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (databaseContainsAuthor($email, $password)) {
        session_start();  //LINE 17
        $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
        return TRUE;
    }
    else {
        session_start();
        unset($_SESSION['loggedIn']);
        unset($_SESSION['email']);
        unset($_SESSION['password']);
        $GLOBALS['loginError'] = 'The specified email address or password was incorrect.';
        return FALSE;
    }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'logout') {
        session_start();
        unset($_SESSION['loggedIn']);
        unset($_SESSION['email']);
        unset($_SESSION['password']);
        header('Location: ' . $_POST['goto']);
        exit();
    }

    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) {
        return databaseContainsAuthor($_SESSION['email'], $_SESSION['password']);
    }
}

function databaseContainsAuthor($email, $password) {
    include_once './db_functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();
    $result = $db->accountExists($email, $password);
    return $result;
}

?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**:
Error logs are showing multiple occurances of this error:

```
PHP Notice:  A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /home3/monitot5/public_html/app/access.php on line 17
```

Access.php line 17:

```
if (databaseContainsAuthor($email, $password)) {
    session_start();  //LINE 17
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: You should call `session_start()` exactly once per request -- no more, no less. It should not be in those `if`/`else` structures or buried in a function, but called at the top of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is to use

```
session_start();
```

at the beginning of `access.php` file and don't use this function any more.

You should also completely change login of your `access.php` file. The first thing you should always do in this file is checking if there's a valid session for this user. Now you check it at the end of file and probably earlier you clear it because you unset session if there are no `$_POST` data.

In addition you shouldn't also use password in your session. It's rather very insecure. You should simple store login for your system when user filled in form valid username/email and password and unset it if user has logged out.

Sorry, but I won't write the whole code for you. You should simple look at some examples of code in Google to check how to handle user login/logout in PHP.